# Scraping iTunes Reviews

Tags: ios, r, xml, web-scraping, itunes

I have been using the `itunesr` package to scrape reviews from the app store and was wondering if anyone could help me create a loop that would scrape all the pages iteratively, rather than doing it page by page as I have been

```
   XX_reviews1 <- getReviews(123456789,'us',1)
   XX_reviews2 <- getReviews(123456789,'us',2)
   XX_reviews3 <- getReviews(123456789,'us',3)
   XX_reviews4 <- getReviews(123456789,'us',4)

fb_reviews <- rbind(fb_reviews1,fb_reviews2,fb_reviews3,fb_reviews4)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure how you are planning on coding this but loops in R are slow and you may want to avoid them. If you plan to use `foreach` at all then look into the [doParallel](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/doParallel.pdf) package. This allows you to run more code at once.. _The parallel package from R 2.14.0 and later provides functions for parallel execution of R code
on machines with multiple cores or processors or multiple computers._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about the `itunesr` package, but generally you can use the `lapply` function to apply a function for/to multiple inputs. The general setup is something this:

```
results <- lapply(inputs, function(n) {...})
```

where at the dots you do something with n. And in your case you want to then combine it to a `data.frame`, which can be done for list with the `dplyr` package:

```
install.packages('dplyr') # If you don't have it yet
library(dplyr)
dplyr::rbind_list(lapply(1:4, function(n) {getReviews(123456789,'us',n)}))
```